# What is the difference between Q-learning, Deep Q-learning and Deep Q-network?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl

**Q-learning** uses a table to store all state-action pairs. Q-learning is a model-free RL algorithm, so how could there be the one called **Deep Q-learning**, as *deep* means using DNN; or maybe the state-action table (Q-table) is still there but the DNN is only for input reception (e.g. turning images into vectors)?

Deep Q-network seems to be only the DNN part of the Deep Q-learning program, and Q-network seems the short for Deep Q-network.

**Q-learning**, **Deep Q-learning**, and **Deep Q-network**, what are the differences? May be there a comparison table between these 3 terms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Q-learning (and in general value based reinforcement learning) we are typically interested in learning a Q-function, $Q(s, a)$. This is defined as
$$Q(s, a) = \mathbb{E}_\pi\left[ G_t | S_t = s, A_t = a \right]\;.$$

For tabular Q-learning, where you have a finite state and action space you can maintain a table lookup that maintains your current estimate of the Q-value. Note that in practice even the spaces being finite might not be enough to *not* use DQN, if e.g. your state space contains a large number, say $10^{10000}$, of states, then it might not be manageable to maintain a separate Q-function for each state-action pair

When you have an infinite state space (and/or action space) then it becomes impossible to use a table, and so you need to use function approximation to generalise across states. This is typically done using a deep neural network due to their expressive power. As a technical aside, the Q-networks don't usually take state *and* action as input, but take in a representation of the state (e.g. a $d$-dimensional vector, or an image) and output a real valued vector of size $|\mathcal{A}|$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is the action space.

Now, it seems in your question that you're confused as to why you use a model (the neural network) when Q-learning is, as you rightly say, model-free. The answer here is that when we talk about Reinforcement Learnings being model-free we are not talking about how their value-functions or policy are parameterised, we are actually talking about whether the algorithms use a model of the transition dynamics to help with their learning. That is, a model free algorithm doesn't use any knowledge about $p(s' | s, a)$ whereas model-based methods look to use this transition function - either because it is known exactly such as in Atari environments, or it must need to be approximated - to perform planning with the dynamics.

Comment: what is that q-network output vector? kinda softmax prob values of all actions?

Comment: no, just real valued numbers. If you look at the expectation, it is not a probability nor does it have any bounds, so the output of the network reflects this.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a table that attempts to *systematically* show the differences between tabular Q-learning (TQL), deep Q-learning (DQL), and deep Q-network (DQN).

|  | Tabular Q-learning (TQL) | Deep Q-learning (DQL) | Deep Q-network (DQN) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Is it an RL algorithm? | Yes | Yes | No (unless you use DQN to refer to DQL, which is done often!) |
| Does it use neural networks? | No. It uses a table. | Yes | No. DQN is the neural network. |
| Is it a model? | No | No | [Yes](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/25460/2444) ([but usually not in the RL sense](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/4456/2444)) |
| Can it deal with continuous state spaces? | No (unless you discretize them) | [Yes](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/12257/2444) | Yes (in the sense that it can get real-valued inputs for the states) |
| Can it deal with continuous action spaces? | [Yes](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/12257/2444) (but maybe not a good idea) | [Yes](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/12257/2444) (but maybe not a good idea) | Yes (but only the sense that it can produce real-valued outputs for actions). |
| Does it converge? | [Yes](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11679/2444) | [Not necessarily](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11679/2444) | [Not necessarily](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11679/2444) |
| Is it an online learning algorithm? | Yes | No, if you use [experience replay](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/6579/2444) | [No, but it can be used in an online learning setting](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/10839/2444) |

Comment: Note that, when I say that neural networks are not online learning algorithms, I'm viewing neural networks as models and not algorithms. However, given that a specific neural network (with specific weights) computes some function and functions are algorithms (see [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)), they could also be considered _algorithms_. In most cases, the best way to think of a neural network is as a _model_ (i.e. something that you can use to approximate the desired function), but, sometimes, it's also useful to think of a neural network as a function.